# nginx .conf, download mp4 file only if there's a specific word in a query param

Tags: nginx

i have this code:

```
map $arg_dl $mimetype {
            1       application/octet-stream;
            default video/mp4;
    }

    server {
            listen          80;
            server_name     example.com www.example.com;
            root            /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index           index.html;

            location ~ \.mp4$ {
                    types {
                            $mimetype mp4;
                    }
                    default_type $mimetype;
            }

            error_page 404 /404.html;
```

the problem is that if I insert in the link of the video .mp4? dl = 1 I download the video correctly, but if I open the link of the video with url .mp4 or .mp4? dl = gfgfgf anyway the browser downloads the video.
how can i solve? I need to download the video only if there is a one in the query and if there are other parameters to view the video in streaming. how can I do? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you cannot set `types` and `default_type` within an `if` block or with a mapped variable. One solution is to use a special URI in a `location` marked `internal` to handle the specific MIME type you require.

```
server {
    ...
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location ~ \.mp4$ {
        if ($arg_dl) { rewrite ^ /download$uri last; }
        ...
    }
    location ^~ /download/ {
        internal;
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        types {}
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        expires -1;
    }
    ...
}
```

The `^~` modifier avoids ambiguity with other regular expression locations. The `internal` prevents `/download` being accessed directly. The `location` and `alias` should both end with a `/` or neither end with a `/`.

Comment: it doesn't work, it returns me 404 error. I used that solution on purpose because the one you proposed does not work. Can't fix my solution?

Comment: What entries are in the access log and error log?

Comment: GET /001.mp4 [404] (0.000) -> 270 bytes and  GET /001.mp4?dl=1 [404] (0.000) -> 270 bytes, the error log is empty